# Approval Workflow - Moving document to a read only document library

Tags: workflow, permissions

I have a document library (doclib1) with an approval workflow attached to it.
On approval of a document I need to move the document to a separate document library (doclib2) which is read only and then delete the document from the original document library.

Before making doclib2 read only I added the following 2 additional actions to the workflow in SPD:

- When the document is approved:

  - Copy the file to the doclib2 document library
  - Delete the document from the doclib1 document library

This worked fine, but then I changed the library permissions on doclib2 the workflow fails with a Access Denied error.

I "Stopped Inheriting Permissions" removed the other permissions and granted:

- "SHAREPOINT\system" account Full Control permissions
- "Authenticated Users" Read Only permissions

But this doesn't seem to work. Can someone please help point me in the right direction to get this working?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Nice and simple explanation why are you receiving this error can be found here:

[Declarative Workflows and User Context](https://web.archive.org/web/20150920144341/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdesigner/archive/2008/09/28/declarative-workflows-and-user-context.aspx)

> The basic thing to remember is that declarative workflows (the one’s
> created by SharePoint Designer) always run impersonating the user who
> started the workflow

If you are using 2010 then you are lucky because:

[Workflow Improvements in SharePoint Designer 2010](https://web.archive.org/web/20110831134953/http://blogs.kraftkennedy.com:80/index.php/2011/01/10/workflow-improvements-in-sharepoint-designer-2010)

> SharePoint Designer 2010 gives you the ability to create impersonation
> steps, which run in the security context of the workflow author.  So
> it’s simple to create an entire process that will run in the context
> of the item submitter, but have one step which runs with elevated
> permissions.  In that way we could setup an HR workflow that checks
> how many vacation days you have left and updates the number, without
> having to give the actual user anything more than read rights to the
> HR list.  You only need to make sure the workflow author has the
> elevated permissions required on the list.

If you are using 2007 then possible solution is using [SPDActivities](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=spdactivities) project at CodePlex and [Copy List Item Extended Activity](https://web.archive.org/web/20110303005614/http://spdactivities.codeplex.com:80/wikipage?title=Copy%20List%20Item%20Extended%20Activity). However I never use it myself and I am not sure it will work. There is also nice little disclaimer at bottom of the page.

Note: You don't need to add FullControl permission to SHAREPOINT\system account since this account already has all permissions.