# SharePoint Online Flow to send an email a year after modified date

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, document-library, information-lifecycle-management

I need to create a flow that will send an email to a specific address a year after a KB article was last modified in a document library, the email needs to contain a link to the KB article and also who created it.

This needs to be an ongoing flow till the end of time itself.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to use an Information Management Policy.  When the Modified Date + 1 year is reached, it will trigger a workflow to send an email.

Check out [this post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/229443/creating-an-document-expiration-policy-sharepoint-online/229445#229445), the question is similar to yours and you could refer to my answer there.  Have a read of the comments too, they might prove useful too.  Make sure you read the link I've embedded in my Answer too, it'll be useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Create a flow that is based on a schedule. Each night, connect to the library, loop through all items and check to see if the modified date meets your criteria, and send the email. Of course, this will send another email the next night again if no one modifies the file. Or, better, configure the "get items" action to use a filter so that it only gets the items that meet your condition.

Instructions for setting up a flow to run on a schedule are [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/flow/run-scheduled-tasks). Instructions for getting items from a list that are filtered by date, instead of all items, are [here](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/FLOW-Get-Items-Filter-SharePoint-list-on-Date/td-p/85238).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, doesn't the get items action only work on lists? I need to do this on a document library.

Comment: Correct, use the "get files (properties only)" action