# Copy an Attachement from one list to another with SharePoint Designer

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow

I'm having issues copying over an attachment from one list to another via SharePoint designer.  I was able to copy over other fields using the Create Item Action in SharePoint Designer.  However, the attachment itself isn't working.

It looks like this is possible, as, Nigel says he's done it here:  [Approval Workflow - Moving document to a read only document library](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/27329/approval-workflow-moving-document-to-a-read-only-document-library)

However, I keep getting an error message.  Also, this needs to be done using SP Designer.

Comment: What version of SharePoint are you using?

Comment: using sharepoint 2010

Comment: This blog has several ideas that might help you. http://jtlovessharepoint.blogspot.com/2010/06/moving-list-with-large-attachments.html

Comment: Thank you, the blog entry is interesting, but not going to solve my issue.  I want to copy the attachment on all new entries to List A to List B, along with 5 other fields, that are working using the Create Item action.

Comment: On a side note:  I cannot locate the Attached Files Folder as seen in the first graphic on the blog.  Where exactly is it located on SP Designer?

Comment: Can you walk through how you set up the "Create New List Item" action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure this out.  My issue was that the Copy item action doesn't work unless you put a conidtion before it.  Therefore, it wouldn't copy, but just run an error.  However, the create item doesn't need a condition.  Not sure the reason for this.

Answer (score 3):

You can copy a list item to another list as well as the same list if need be.  Create a workflow "Copy Item in Current Item to (Target List).  Now go into Sharepoint designer and find your list, Look for Custom Actions on the lower right hand side of your screen, click new, and Give it a name (I used Copy List Item) Set it to Initiate Workflow, pick the workflow you just created and click ok.  It will copy all of the data including the attachments.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think this is possible OOTB, but, you can create a custom SharePoint Designer Activity and use that?
Please see the link below:
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/120ea459-2b04-4978-869e-555d8071926e/how-to-copy-list-item-attachment-to-document-library-in-sharepoint-designer-workflows